# install boot with raid 1 in 3 TB disks

Tags: boot, raid1, gpt, mbr

I'm trying to install /boot in a RAID 1 using 3 TB disks. As the RAID partition do not let you manage partitions than more than 2 TB, CentOS automatically configures the partitions using GPT.

My current machine (HP Proliant ML110 G4) does not support EFI/GPT so it uses MBR to boot the system. If I configured the /boot using a standard partition it works but it does not work if I installed the /boot using RAID 1. The system can not boot and it does not throw any error. Is it possible to install /boot in a RAID 1 with 3 TB disks if my system does not support EFI? I'm using CentOS 6.3.

Answer (score 2):

Did you make sure to install the boot loader on all of the hard drives? With a raid1 set as your boot partition you have to install grub on each hard drive in turn - or at least you used to with smaller disks using MBR partitioning

I'm just now doing this on a server I have (upgrading storage space) so I'm curious if you found an answer

And to those that say "don't do this, it's ridiculous", what's ridiculous is purchasing a new server you'll just have to landfill later, and which probably uses more energy than the one it's replacing (if the one its replacing was built for low power to begin with) just so you can have a whizzy server getting even more bored than the one it replaced as it is dishing out bits as a NAS when it's bottlenecked by the network anyway. The moral is to never question why people are doing things, in context almost anything makes sense.